# How to access remote sql server located in other place

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have shared published website and the database files to our client.
they have restored the database to their server.

Now they have changed the connection string in web.config with new server name/IP address and a proper user name and password.

My client said that he can login sql server using the same password and username. But when the website is launched through IIS with same (username and password in web.config and same db structure), it gives an error:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

---

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=53&LinkId=20476

---

Error Number: 53
Severity: 20
State: 0

The ip address of the server starts with 172.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide the specific permission on server for particular client

Answer (score 0):

I would check these things:

- I would check the [SQL Server Configuration Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174212.aspx) to see if the TCP/IP communication is enabled.
- I would check the **firewall settings**. A firewall could prevent traffic from/to the server.
- I would check if another application from the same client can connect to the same server. Then I would check the **connection string differences**.
- If all of the above were playing correctly, then I would **check the privileges on the specific SQL Server, on the specific database, for the account I am trying to connect with**. Allow everyone to use this database as a first step to check if it is an account-permissions problem.

You could check [this connection strings example post](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).

Hope I helped!

Comment: I started the sqlserver service in sqlserver config tool,
enabled TCP/IP in network configuration.


What I did was just sent a fresh published files of my website and replaced old files in wwwroot folder and launched them and it worked!

Comment: Nice. If everything works, then I guess there is no problem to solve.

Comment: Hi Pantelis natsiavas, thanks for your reply. I appreciate it.

I started the sqlserver service in sqlserver config tool which was stopped,
enabled TCP/IP in network configuration which was disabled and launched the website again but it didn't work


What I did next was I sent a fresh published files of my website and replaced old files in wwwroot folder and launched them and it worked and connection established!

Comment: Glad to help. Since my answer was useful, please upvote it. It is crucial for people navigating to your question to be able to identify helpful questions quickly.

Comment: Vote up requires 15 reputation. I always vote up. Next time I will.
Thanks so much.
 :)